How to integrate out the dynamical gauge field in the relativistic Abelian-Higgs action?
I am trying to understand the effective current-current interactions that a theory with a complex scalar field generates when one integrates out a dynamical gauge field. This is in context of understanding the boson-vortex duality in 2+1 dimensions.
I consider the following action,
$$ S=\int \textrm{d} \tau\textrm{d}^2\mathbf{x}\left[-|D_\mu\phi|^2-m^2|\phi|^2-U|\phi|^4-\frac{1}{g^2}f_{\mu\nu}f^{\mu\nu}\right]$$
Let $U$>0 and $m^2<0$. In that case, the scalar field condenses and by the Higgs mechanism both the photon and $\phi$ are gapped. I want to now integrate out the gapped gauge field and find the effective long-ranged current-current interactions.
My attempt is as follows. I rewrite the Lagrangian density as,
$$ L=-|\partial_\mu\phi|^2-m^2|\phi|^2-U|\phi|^4+\frac{1}{2}a_\nu K^\nu_\mu a^\mu-j_\mu a^\mu $$ where the kernel is given by
$$K^\nu_\mu= -\frac{4}{g^2}\left[\partial_\mu\partial^\nu-\delta^\mu_\nu\Box\right]+2\delta^\mu_\nu|\phi|^2 $$
and the current is given by
$$ j_\mu = \textrm{i} \left[\phi\partial_\mu\phi^\dagger-\phi^\dagger\partial_\mu\phi\right]. $$
I now know that integrating out the gauge field gives me a Lagrangian density given by,
$$L = -|\partial_\mu\phi|^2-m^2|\phi|^2-U|\phi|^4-\frac{1}{2}j_\nu [K^{-1}]^\nu_\mu j^\mu .$$
I am unable to proceed from here. How do I invert the kernel and obtain an effective interaction? What I am also worried about is the $|\phi|^2$ in the kernel, and so it seems that the the long-ranged current-current interactions also depend on the value of the field $|\phi|$? I've heard that these long-ranged interactions in 2 dimensions are actually logarithmic, but how does one show this from the expression of the kernel I have computed?
I have some idea that I should fix a gauge and go to momentum space, but I do not exactly see yet how to undertake this or how it helps.
Edit 1:
I figured out that in the transverse gauge, the kernel simplifies to,
$$K^\nu_\mu= \delta_\mu^\nu\left[\frac{4}{g^2}\Box+2|\phi|^2\right]  $$
I now understand how to invert $\Box$ in momentum space, but I don't understand how to handle the $|\phi^2|$. Is is that when the scalar field condenses, I can treat $|\phi|^2$ as a constant? This is probably true but only deep in the condensate phase?
Edit 2: What I've stated in Edit 1 is NOT correct. Since the Higgs mechanism gives a mass to the photon in the Mott insulating phase, I lose gauge invariance and no longer have the freedom to choose a gauge. Working in the Coulomb gauge wlog is only valid near the critical point, where the photon is approximately massless.

I'm following the convention in Srednicki's book, with the mostly positive metric signature.

Where did they $\phi$-square term in the kernel come from? Perhaps you can show a bit more of your derivation.

It comes from the covariant derivative. $-|D_\mu\phi|^2=-|(\partial_\mu-\textrm{i}a_\mu)\phi|^2$ which would give a term proportional to $|\phi|^2$ in the kernel.
